# Buffered Reader/Writer VS Buffered Input/Output Stream to transfer files via FTP

Tags: iostream, urlconnection, writer, buffered

I have been reading on URL and URLConnection and I know that both Buffered InputStream/OutputStream (for character streams) and, Buffered Reader/Writer (for byte streams) can be used to transfer the file from one ftp to another via URL and URLConnection. But I'm wondering which one is better to use? My source ftp is of Windows 2003 OS and the destination ftp is of Unix OS. The files coming from the source ftp will be processed in the destination ftp so character representation/file format must stay the same.